# if statements with while loops

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I want to make it that after 10 sec you get and random letter of an random word and that the timer starts again like an infinite loop. Here is my code:

```
words = ["graveyard","church","apple","tree","crispy","air"]
hidden_word = random.choice(words)
hint = random.sample(hidden_word,1)

timer = 0

if timer == 10:
   print(hint)
else:
   while timer < 10:
        timer = timer + 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(timer)
```

I tried to place the if statement in the while loop but didn't work it only gave me errors

Comment: `if timer == 10` cannot possibly be true, because the previous line sets it to zero...

Comment: *I tried to place the if statement in the while loop but didn't work it only gave me errors* - we don't know how you placed it there and which errors you got. Please show code and error.

Comment: Please do not use images to show code

Comment: why i set it to zero is zo it will always start of as zero i think, but like i said i just started so i have no idea

Comment: How is it supposed to end? Is the user supposed to guess the word?

Comment: I use an image because it said that I cant paste the code in there

Comment: eventually the user is supposed to guess the word yeah but idk how I'm gonna do that but that is part of my journey of learning to program

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you described, but it will never stop:

```
import time
import random

words = ["graveyard","church","apple","tree","crispy","air"]
hidden_word = random.choice(words)
hint = random.sample(hidden_word,1)

def random_select():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        print(hint)

random_select()
```

Comment: it is good practice to put things in functions

Comment: I agree. I'm pointing out that you're never calling it, though, therefore script will end